# Implementing MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL on dronekit

Tags: dronekit-python

I've been trying to implement the set_message_interval in my script using the example in the documentation. I am trying to increase the rate at which I receive Mavlink messages. I get a low amount of IMU messages per second and I want to increase it so I wanted to use this command to increase the frequency of the Mavlink messages. Here is my code:

```
def set_message_interval(attribute, time):
      msg = vehicle.message_factory.command_long_encode(
      0, 0, #target system, target component
      mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL, #command
      0, #confirmation
      attribute, #param 1
      time, #param 2
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0) #param 3-7 not used
      vehicle.send_mavlink(msg)
```

I call the function but whenever I declare a message listener in main I still receive the messages at the same rate. I was expecting for the listener to more IMU data in 1 second but it stays the same. Any one have any ideas on what's wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Although Mavlink's documentation encourages the use of [MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL), it isn't supported in [Ardupilot's documentation](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/copter-commands-in-guided-mode.html).

Instead try using the supported command [REQUEST_DATA_STREAM](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#REQUEST_DATA_STREAM) and setting the coresponding value of [MAV_DATA_STREAM](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#MAV_DATA_STREAM). The command is supported by Dronekit's message factory like so:

```
msg = vehicle.message_factory.request_data_stream_encode(
    0, 0,
    mavutil.mavlink.MAV_DATA_STREAM_RAW_SENSORS, # Including IMU
    10, # Rate (Hz)
    1) # Turn on
    vehicle.send_mavlink(msg)
```